# Owl-carousel missing alt attributes

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel, alt-attribute

Does anyone know how to get the alt attribute tag in the code on the owl carousel? The alt text appears in the media files, but don't appear in the code and Google is saying they're missing which isn't helping with SEO.

Here's an example:
div.nav-container > div.navbar-header > a.navbarbrand-no-break > img.lazyloaded

FYI - Someone else developed the site using WordPress and a proprietary custom theme.

Thanks in advance.

I looked at the files in the media library and they all have alt text.
There's no way for me to access the code or plugin.

Comment: If you're using custom theme then you need to check in the files and needs to fetch the alt tag using PHP.